# Reading USB-GPS info with Python

Tags: python, gps, usb, pyserial

I've written a small python script that uses information from a usb gps dongle. This far I've been working in linux where I could just identify the device in /dev/ and read NMEA data from it using pySerial. This isn't a perfect solution though and it's not platform independent in any way so I started looking at pyUSB to try to communicate with the device.

The device:

- Product name: ND-100S
- baud rate:    4800
- USB class:    0xEF
- subclass:     2

My problem is that I know very little about usb so I don't know how to initialize and read sentences from it.

My testing code this far looks like:

```
import usb
import sys

device = usb.core.find(bDeviceClass=0xef)

print " + Class: %s" % device.bDeviceClass
print " + Subclass: %i" % device.bDeviceSubClass
print " + Protocol: %i" % device.bDeviceProtocol
print " + Length  : %s" % device.bLength
print " + Configurations: %i" % device.bNumConfigurations
```

... Mostly just getting information about the device.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Have you considered using gpsd? It runs on Linux, *BSD and MacOSX and apparently [Windows](https://code.google.com/p/gpsd-4-win/) too.

Answer (score 0):

even if it is USB dongle, you communicate with GPS device via serial interface only. However, there are a dozen of NMEA flavors so if you want it to be more platform independent, I would suggest using python-gpsd.